# is there any problem whih my code for adding new cattegories?

Tags: php, categorization

I have written this code for my eshop so that i can add new categories for the products that i sell.Can anyone please tell me if my code is correct so that i can upload it? Or if there is any problem with it? Can you tell me so that I can fix it and make it work properly?

```
<form action="" method="post" style="padding:80px;">

<b>Insert New Category:</b>
<input type="text" name="new_cat" required/> 
<input type="submit" name="add_cat" value="Add Category" /> 

</form>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['add_cat'])){

    $new_cat = $_POST['new_cat'];

    $insert_cat = "insert into categories (cat_title) values ('$new_cat')";
    $run_cat = mysqli_query($con, $insert_cat); 

    if($run_cat){

    echo "<script>alert('New Category has been inserted!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('eshop.php?view_cats','_self')</script>";
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to prevent the SQL injections like Jonnix said in the comments:

```
$new_cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['new_cat']);
```

Comment: Learning parameterized queries would be a better long-term approach, though.